# When using semver (Semantic Versioning) should the patch version Z (x.y.Z) be returned to 0 when Y is changed?

Tags: version, versioning

From [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/):

> Patch version Z (x.y.Z | x > 0) MUST be incremented if only backwards
>   compatible bug fixes are introduced. A bug fix is defined as an
>   internal change that fixes incorrect behavior.

Suppose I have a program at version **0.1.12**. If I had to increment Y (**0.Y.12**), should I return Z (0.2.Z) to 0 (becoming **0.2.0**) or just keep it unaltered (becoming **0.2.12**)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. All numbers should be reset when their parent version is changed.

The specification (http://semver.org/) states:

> Patch version MUST be reset to 0 when minor version is incremented.

Comment: Indeed, it wouldn't make sense otherwise, but since I couldn't find this info from the original specification, I would like to know what is the way people do it.

Comment: As I said, all I've seen is people doing it the way I described above.

Comment: Yep, I know. :) I think the best thing to do is open an issue at project's github page.

Comment: "When a major version number is incremented, the minor version and patch version MUST be reset to zero. When a minor version number is incremented, the patch version MUST be reset to zero. For instance: 1.1.3 -> 2.0.0 and 2.1.7 -> 2.2.0." http://semver.org/spec/v1.0.0.html

Comment: The Spec does state this explicitly, in both released versions of the spec (1.0.0 and 2.0.0-rc.1). See point #3 or @theazureshadow's comment above which quotes it.